# How to simplify this LINQ Query with Distinct on each column into a single statement

Tags: linq

Here's the LINQ query I have, it gets the unique value for each selected column and stores them as a list in a dictionary.

```
var serialTable = serialNoAdapter.GetData();
var distinctValue = (from row in serialTable
                    select new
                    {
                        row.CodePractice,
                       row.LockType,
                       row.Software
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
var softwareValue = distinctValue.Select(p => p.Software).Distinct().ToList();
var codeValue = distinctValue.Select(p => p.CodePractice).Distinct().ToList();
var lockValue = distinctValue.Select(p => p.LockType).Distinct().ToList();

return new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
       {
           {"software", softwareValue},
           {"codepractice", codeValue},
           {"locktype", lockValue}
       };
```

The only problem is it is broken up into a few statements. My question is is it possible to simplify it and compact it into a single statement?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can simplify it substantially by ommitting the middle step.

```
var softwareValue = serialTable.Select(p => p.Software).Distinct().ToList();
var codeValue = serialTable.Select(p => p.CodePractice).Distinct().ToList();
var lockValue = serialTable.Select(p => p.LockType).Distinct().ToList();

return new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
       {
           {"software", softwareValue},
           {"codepractice", codeValue},
           {"locktype", lockValue}
       };
```

Maybe others can improve further.

Comment: With this approach, i think you are querying the database 3 times instead of 1...is it the case?

Comment: Probably.  Whether that matters, and how to optimize properly, will depend on your exact circumstances.  Profile with real data.